# Copy selected rows twice

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I've written a really rudimentary Excel macro to copy the selected row twice, then move the cursor down 3 rows so the process can be repeated again.

So if I have a file where the first 10 rows all need to be repeated twice, I run the macro 10 times.

This already saves me a bunch of keystrokes, but I'm sure it could be written better so I simply select the first 10 rows and then run the macro once.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Copy_Twice()
' Copies current row twice

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=3).Select

End Sub
```

For every file I run this macro, it may not be the first 10 rows to be copied.

In fact an even better macro would be to copy every row twice if the cell in Column J is blank.

Update: File has a header row with values for columns A to X.  The rows to be copied will be the first x # of rows after the header where column J is blank.  So in one example, rows 2-11 need to be duplicated twice.  But in another file, it may be rows 2-21.

Comment: What version of Excel are you running? Can you be more specific about the nature of the values?

Comment: Excel 2010.  I updated my question with a brief explanation of my file

Comment: Is there a column that can be relied upon to have values down to the extents of he work? It cannot be column J as that column dictates whether the rows get copied but typically in a data block there is at least one column that is always filled.

Comment: Column A always has data in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim n&, x&
n = 0
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("J:J"), " ")
Range("A2").Select

While n <> x
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
    n = n + 1
Wend
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This should work to copy 10 rows but if my next file requires 15 rows copied I would need to edit the macro. What if I add a dialog box to prompt the user for the number of rows to be copied? Or could you help with the 2nd part of my question which is to copy each row where column J is empty?

Comment: Please see updated post. for the second part of your question it is better to provide data sample or screenshot

Comment: So far this is the best answer.  Instead of the inputbox, I selected the rows to be copied (or the blank cells in column J) and changed your variable declaration to `x = Selection.Rows.Count`.  This way it removes the message prompt.  Can I make it even smarter by using `COUNTBLANK` to see how many blank cells are in column J?  Note that Column A has values in all cells so it can be used to determine the last row to count.

Comment: I just realized that the rows in column J to be copied are not blank, they actually contain a space.  I've updated your code to count the number of rows to be copied, and then I'm using the rest of your code.  This works for me!

Answer (score 3):

Can I play too? :P

Here is the fastest way to do it. Let's say your data is from cell `A1:A10`. Simply run this code.

**You don't have to use Copy/Paste at all**.

What this code does is, inserts the blank rows and then simulates the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> --> Special --> Blank Cells --> Fill blank cell with data from the above row using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
For i = 10 To 2 Step -1
    Rows(i).Insert: Rows(i).Insert
Next i

'~~> After the blank rows are inserted your range will
'~~> expand up to row 30
Range("A1:A30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
Range("A1:A30").Value = Range("A1:A30").Value '<~~ Convert formuals back to values
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool solution indeed!  The only thing is I forgot to mention there is a header row, so when I said first 10 rows I really meant first 10 rows *after* the header (i.e. rows 2-11).  Also your macro only copies values in column A, rather than the entire row.

Comment: @wongnog: That should not be a problem. The line `For i = 10 To 2 Step -1` becomes `For i = 11 To 3 Step -1` and `A1:A30` becomes `A2:A31` :)

Comment: @wongnog: Just saw your edit. If you want to do it for multiple columns then simply replace `A2:A31` to `A2:F31`. I am assuming that the data is till column `F`. Replace `F` with the relevant column Letter

Comment: @Siddharth This only partially works, as it copies the values in Column A but not the entire row.  Also I will have to manually change the 'For i = 11' and 'A2:A31' code for every file as it may not be the same # of rows.  

I've updated my original post to describe my file better.  Are you able to help with the 2nd part, which is to only duplicate rows where column J is blank?

Comment: Yeah if you understand the logic then it is very simple :) in my code you can always use variables in lieu of hard coded values. For example `For i = startRow To EndRow` Regarding `2-11` or `2-21` how is that ascertained?

Comment: It should copy rows 2-11 twice if the values in J2:J11 are blank, or rows 2-21 if J2:J21 are blank

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will allow the user to input the row count and test if column J is blank for each row:

```
Sub CopyRows()

Dim x As Integer
x = InputBox("How Many Rows to Copy?", 8)

Dim c As Range
Set c = Range("A2")

Dim y As Integer

For y = x to c.Row Step -1

    If IsEmpty(Cells(y, "J")) Then

        Cells(y,1).EntireRow.Copy: Cells(y,1).Resize(2,1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This should work except I get an error because variable c has not been declared.  Also forgot to mention that I have a header row, so if I want to copy the first 10 rows it's really row 2-11.

Comment: Okay. Try it now. I just made `c = Range("A2")` but you can adjust as needed. I assumed `ActiveCell` was there for a **specific** reason, so that the user could insert rows after whatever cell he was on.

Comment: ActiveCell makes more sense but somehow your loop doesn't work with it.  It also doesn't work with c = Range("A2").  I've updated my original post with a brief description of my file.

Comment: See the code now. I forgot that we need to step backward from the last row (user defined) to the first row (2-according to your specs). Also `ActiveCell` is **never** the best thing to use, *unless* you absolutely **need** it.

Comment: For both versions, it brings up the prompt for how many rows to copy but after that it says "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".  When I press Debug, it highlights the "c = " row in the VBA

Comment: ugh ... it's Monday morning. I forgot the `Set`. I just edited that in there.

Comment: Ok I no longer get an error with the "set" line, but then nothing else happens (i.e. nothing inserted, selected, copied, or pasted)

Comment: So, is column J really the column to check? Or is the data empty text strings? What if you change  `IsEmpty(Cells(y, "J"))` to `Len(Cells(y,"J")) = 0`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Yes column J is the one to check but the rows to be copied have a blank space and are not empty

Answer (score 0):

If column A can be relied upon to show the extents of the rows to be processed then finding the last populated row in column A and working toward row 2 should cover all of the rows to be processed.

```
Sub add_Duplicate_Blank_Js()
    Dim rw As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For rw = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                If Not CBool(Len(.Cells(rw, "J"))) Then
                    With .Rows(rw).Cells
                        .Copy
                        .Resize(2, .Columns.Count).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    End With
                End If
            Next rw
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

With the titles across the first row and column A populated down to the full scope of the data, the above will walk backwards from the bottom to the top (recommended when inserting or deleting rows in a [For Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)) of the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx).

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately running the code produces no results

Comment: Are the governing cells in column J truly blank or do they contain zero-length strings returned by formulas?

Comment: Aahhhh I am so stupid!  The empty cells in Column J actually contain a space.

Comment: @wongnog - I've adjusted the code to trim out the space and look for a zero-length.